# AWK - Unable to update the files

Tags: bash, awk

I have 300 txt files in my directory in the following format

```
 regional_vol_WM_atlas[1-300].txt

    651328 651328
    553949 553949
    307287 307287
    2558 2558
```

The following awk script was supposed to create a new file by performing calculation on fourth row of each existing files in my directory .

```
#!/bin/bash

awk=/usr/bin/awk

awkcommand='
FNR == 1 {
  newfilename = FILENAME ; sub(".txt", "_prop.txt", newfilename)
  printf "" > newf
ilename
}
FNR == 4 {
  $1=($1/0.824198)*0.8490061
  $2=($2/0.824198)*0.8490061
}
{
  print >> newfilename
}
 'regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9].txt regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9][0-9].txt regional_vol_WM_atlas1[0-4][0-9].txt regional_vol_WM_atlas15[02].txt
```

Unfortunately i could not update any file in the directory ,when i run the file, i am incurring following error

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/media/dev/Daten/Task1/subject1/t1$ '/media/dev/Daten/Task1/subject1/t1/Method' 

/media/dev/Daten/Task1/subject1/t1/Method: line 18: regional_vol_WM_atlas10.txt: command not found
```

Could you please correct me where i am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is not calling awk.  It defines a variable named awk and then tries to execute the file `regional_vol_WM_atlas10.txt` with the variable `awkcommand` set in its environment.  Alas, that file is not in your PATH, so bash cannot find it.  You need to instead do:

```
awk "$awkcommand" file1 file2 ...
```

(where `file1`, `file2`, etc. are the input files you want to use as input.)

Also, note that your current script is appending the literal text `regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9].txt` to the end of the awk command (or if a file exists which matches that glob, the name of that file is being appended), which you do not want.  Overall, what you were trying to do should have been written:

```
  #!/bin/bash

    awkcommand='
    FNR == 1 {
      newfilename = FILENAME ; sub(".txt", "_prop.txt", newfilename)
      printf "" > newfilename
    }
    FNR == 4 {
      $1=($1/0.824198)*0.8490061
      $2=($2/0.824198)*0.8490061
    }
    {
      print >> newfilename
    }
    '

    awk "$awkcommand" regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9].txt \
        regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9][0-9].txt \
        regional_vol_WM_atlas1[0-4][0-9].txt \
        regional_vol_WM_atlas15[02].txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction, now i am able to solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a variable can be assigned for a command, for example:

```
x='hello' some_command
```

Which in effect is what bash thinks you are trying to do.  The culprit is the whitespace, which acts as a command separator, so just escape (prefix with a `\`) the whitespace in the list of filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk=/usr/bin/awk

awkcommand='
FNR == 1 {
  newfilename = FILENAME ; sub(".txt", "_prop.txt", newfilename)
  printf "" > newf
ilename
}
FNR == 4 {
  $1=($1/0.824198)*0.8490061
  $2=($2/0.824198)*0.8490061
}
{
  print >> newfilename
}
 '\ regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9].txt\ regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-9][0-9].txt\ regional_vol_WM_atlas1[0-4][0-9].txt\ regional_vol_WM_atlas15[02].txt
```

The only thing I have altered is the final line.